# Angular/CLI -- auto reload doesn't happen

Tags: angular-cli

I recently started working with Angular/CLI tool, I'm facing a problem while executing the file, that is when I run

```
ng serve
```

then this command helps us in auto reloading the site when any changes are made in the source file but in my system it is not happening (i.e. site is not auto reloading and when I forcely reload the site then also it is not getting updated as per changes made in the source file).

The site is getting updated only when I terminate the "ng serve" command and again run the same command("ng serve") then only my site is getting updated.

So it becomes hard for me to terminate the server and connect the server, when ever the changes are made, so I request you people if any one know solution of this problem please help me out.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem a few days back in my linuxOS, and when I read about it, I found that this problem is heavily dependent on the system you use and the way you did your setup for angular-cli, both globally and locally.
So, after reading readme.md created by angular-cli for each project, I tried using `ng-build --watch` but the problem still couldn't be solved because by running this command it should work like `ng-serve` but it only build the app and doesn't even served it on `localhost:4200`.
then, after digging into the problem more deeper I found the problem, it was with my OS, I am using ubuntu, the `inotify/max_user_watches` value 8192, which I crossed, due to which it wasn't showing any changes made further.
So i used these-
`echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p`
and it worked fine.

p.s. in the process i also tumbled upon a solution with these commands -
`rm -rf nodes_modules/` ->
`npm update` ->
`npm install`.
try this before doing above stated canges, if this works for you then you are well and good to go.

Comment: Thanks, the simple "rm -rf nodes_modules/ -> npm update -> npm install" solution worked for me.

Comment: Instead of this, i removed the `node_modules` generated globally(run `npm list -g`) and then reinstalled `npm` by `npm -i -g npm` > `npm update` > `npm install`. I got pointers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748307/how-to-reinstall-broken-npm) answer.

Comment: It is good to remember that the Live Reload happens when changing the component, it does not see changes in `index.html`

Answer (score 34):

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: It is good to remember that the Live Reload happens when changing the component, it does not see changes in `index.html`

Answer (score 25):

Ng serve automatically reload when the files are modified however if the config is messed up then you can try bellow command

```
ng serve --live-reload
```

Answer (score 15):

What worked for me was to simple turn the "compileOnSave" option to "true" inside the tsconfig.js

[image]

Answer (score 9):

run ng serve with sudo, it worked for me

```
sudo ng serve
```

This is only for Linux!

Comment: Why its like this?

Comment: Why was there a need to run it as sudo? Shouldn't it serve you as the normal user too

Comment: even knowing that this shouldn't be the best way to deal with the problem, but in fact it saved me a lot of time, thanks @ThomasJohn

Comment: This is a really terrible answer. Never ever run an application as root that can run under user privledges!! This will also set root permissions for all files create under that process which means the situation will only get worse.

Answer (score 5):

Just run all the following command and I hope it will work.

```
rm -rf nodes_modules/
npm update
npm install
```

and start the server again

```
ng serve -o
```

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this issue because I used WSL to run commands for a project that was under a Windows directory (`/mnt/...`).

To resolve it, I transferred the project directory on the WSL directory (`~/`).

Comment: Do you mean that you transferred the project directory to the WSL directory (`~/`)? Please clarify :)

Comment: Yes, that is true this same problem I was facing I almost lost 4 hours trying to find the solution. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

I am using angular 6 and increasing time on max_user_watches worked for me

```
sudo echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: Works for me but using "sudo su" first.

Answer (score 2):

> it works for me:
>   ng serve --poll=1000

Comment: This was the only approach that worked for me (I'm running the Angular Dev Server inside a docker container based on image of node:fermium)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue in my ubuntu machine. It was due to the permission settings. I changed the workspace permission settings by following the below mentioned steps.

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Type `sudo chmod a+rwx /path/to/file` into the terminal, replacing  “/path/to/file” with the file you want to give
   permissions to everyone for, and press “Enter.” You can also use the
   command `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /path/to/folder` to give permissions to
   a folder and every file and folder inside it. Omit the “x” from
   either command if you don’t want the files to be executable.

I have used `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /path/to/folder`.

3. Type your password at the password prompt and press “Enter.”

Once it is done, do `npm build` and start the application by `ng serve`.

**[OR]**

Simply you can use "sudo ng serve".

Now do the necessary changes in the workspace files and without restart, auto-reload happens. Hope this would be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

If angular auto-reload is not working on **ubuntu 20.04** and you are using **nvm** try running the following:

1. sudo echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
2. Delete **node_modules** in your application's folder
3. npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
4. npm cache verify
5. npm install -g @angular/cli
6. In your application's folder run **npm i**

Hopefully when you run **ng serve** everything should work as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem when my  devDependencies is Angular 7
but install `angular/cli` of version `8.x.x`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.12",
}
```

just remove the cli globally

```
npm unintsall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean -f
```

check the state

```sh
ng version # if remove successfully, the command would no work
```

then install cli again

```sh
sudo npm install @angular/cli@^7.3.8 -g
```

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is MacOS 10.14 or higher, it will show this error when you type "sudo sysctl -p"

> `sysctl: illegal option -- p`

We are going to solve this by changing that instruction to the following

> `sudo sysctl net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive=1`

It worked for me, I hope it works for you too

Answer (score -7):

If you are using **Linux system**  then the below command may be helpful for you

Run below command in terminal

**sudo ng serve**

It works for me !!

Comment: This is a really terrible answer. Never ever run an application as root that can run under user privledges!! This will also set root permissions for all files create under that process which means the situation will only get worse.

Comment: interesting... same answer above has 6 up votes