# How to Reinstall Broken npm

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, uninstallation, reinstall

I just installed node `v9.11.1` when I try to use npm I keep getting the following error:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v9.11.1
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
```

I tried to do `npm i -g npm` but it couldn't update itself, it just kept throwing the same error above.

When I run `npm -v` it says `5.5.1` it seems the latest version is currently `5.8.0`.

I tried deleting the folder and running the repair function on the node.js installer, but it didn't replace the module.

Comment: I ended up with a broken installation of npm as well. In my case, I was getting the following error when attempting to run any npm command:

`TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/socks-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js:114:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
[...]`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Delete the Global NPM Folder

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926706/349659

```
npm list -g
```

For Windows this will most likely be:

`%AppData%\npm\node_modules`

You can paste that into a folder's address bar and it will take you there.

Once there delete the folder named `npm`.

### Download the Latest Release of NPM

https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/latest

Grab the zip and unzip it to your `node_modules` folder that you just deleted the npm folder from.

Rename the folder you extracted from the zip to `npm`

If you get any warnings about the file path or name being too long skip the warnings.

### Update for Good Luck

Now you should be able to run `npm i -g npm` to update/reinstall npm without any warnings.

I find this step especially important if you had errors in Windows about the path or file name being too long.

You may get the following errors. If you do go and delete or move the files it has listed and you should be able to run `npm i -g npm` successfully.

```
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx.cmd: is outside C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd: is outside C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

Comment: if `npm --version` throws an error like "Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module" this answer doesn't help. but I guess OP got a clean `npm` error

Answer (score 21):

Somehow I had a broken installation of npm so reinstalling it with itself (e.g. `npm install -g npm` or similar) would not work.

The [npm readme](https://github.com/npm/cli/tree/v7.6.1#direct-download) actually defines a very simple way to install npm again using this `curl` command:

```
curl -qL https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh
```

This installation script actually removes any existing npm installations, then installs the latest version for you.

Comment: This didn't work. It outputted `failed!` for me

Comment: `curl -qL https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh` worked for me. Simplest solution, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

More info [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/if-your-npm-is-broken).

Comment: I tried to do that but because npm was broken I was unable to run npm to install/reinstall npm.

Comment: In my case, this helped. @cts_ae: Maybe you need to fix the cache first, try `npm cache verify` or `npm cache clean`

Answer (score 6):

Try this command to reinstall npm

```
npm install -g npm-reinstall
```

If you are using a linux distribution add sudo

```
sudo npm install -g npm-reinstall
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I am all about one-liners, let me make this very damn easy for you.

Open your GitBash or Cygwin(I think both GitBash and Cygwin stores the Windows pre-defined Environment Variables and paths in their storage, so this becomes way easy), on any path, and run this one-liner from there:

```sh
rm -rf $APPDATA/npm; npm install -g npm@latest; npm list -g;
```

`rm -rf $APPDATA/npm;` - this will purge the old global `npm` folder completely.

`npm install -g npm@latest;` - this will install the latest version of NPM available(so no need to install minor versions after this ;)).

`npm list -g;` - this will show you details of your NPM global profile.

If anyone insists on doing this in PowerShell then here's the way:

```
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\nodejs\"
cmd /c 'del /s /q /f %APPDATA%\npm && rd /s /q %APPDATA%\npm'; npm install -g npm@latest; npm list -g;
```

`$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\nodejs\"` - Ensures that `Nodejs` is added to `Path` for atleast running PowerShell session. (**Caution:** Run this only once, as long as no errors.).

`cmd /c 'del /s /q /f %APPDATA%\npm && rd /s /q %APPDATA%\npm';` - Ensures that the necessary step of fully purging the `%APPDATA%\npm` folder is done with measure.

Comment: The original problem was that npm was broken thus you cannot use it as a dependency to install itself. I do wonder if this would have worked though since npm wasn't completely borked [looking at my original problem]. I'm unable to reproduce this now, but hopefully this is helpful for others that come along. ++ For automating the delete 

Comment: @CTS_AE Yep, glad to help out with different approach

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions here worked for me. I was able to fix it by doing the following:

**1:** in file explorer, go to %appdata%, open the nodejs folder, and delete the npm folder.

**2:** find the node installer (type "add or remove program" in start menu and search "node" in the settings window), open it, and click "repair"

**or** (get a clean install of both node and npm)

**1:** in file explorer, go to %appdata%, open the nodejs folder, and delete the npm folder.

**2:** find the node installer (type "add or remove program" in start menu and search "node" in the settings window), open it, and click "uninstall"

3: download the latest node installer and install normally. This will update node and npm to the latest versions

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to and delete %AppData%\npm\node_modules\npm
2. Use npm cli repo's curl script to automatically clean previous npm install and re-install the latest version:

`curl -qL https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh`

repo: [npm github repo](https://github.com/npm/cli)

Comment: on mac, I was unable to find the old `npm` path. Ran the above command, it auto removed the old one and installed `npm@latest`

Answer (score 0):

For me even deleting npm folder or reinstalling Node didn't help. After updating Nodejs and npm to latest version (Node 10.19, npm 6.14.3) of my CentOS 6, I've got constant libs error with npm while Node was fine.

What's worked - `n` Node version manager. With this command I could reverse my npm version: `n -p 6.13` [link](https://github.com/tj/n#preserving-npm)

Answer (score 0):

While creating a new react app using `create-react-app`

npm suggested the following:

> Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
> npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:

And it worked for me:

```bash
sudo chown -R 506:20 "/Users/${username}/.npm"
```