# npm not running after Node upgrade

Tags: node.js, npm

I upgraded Node from version 10.17 to 12.6.1 on my Windows 10 Pro x64 machine and npm does not run. The error i get is:

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985   throw err;  ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
>       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }
>   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985   throw err;   ^

I have tried so far:

- All the answers and solutions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm) and the
  issue still persists.
- Uninstalling Node, deleting all npm, node_modules and node folders
  on Program Files and AppData, rebooting, installing node again,
  rebooting and it still did not work.
- Reinstalling npm as per the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748308)

My system Path variable contains `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` and my user Path variable contains `C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm`

What am I missing here? Can anyone guide me?

Comment: what npm -v shows in console ?

Comment: @DeepKakkar The same error which I have posted in the question.

Comment: I believe your node js not installed or configured properly, you should remove and install node js again

Comment: I have tried that, as stated in my question. And the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the folder of node to the folder of the project end update the path end it finally solved the problem no idea why

Comment: maby because "program files" have space between the words end i heard in programing it can cause problems