# Vue, vite: GET http://localhost:3000/@vite/client net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: vue.js, http-status-code-404, vite

I am using Vue and vite to practice the workflow of the web application with fetching API, following this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/fetching-data-third-party-api-vue-axios/). At the end of the `yarn dev` command, I got the error. I've tried:

1. Directly clone the [project](https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/vue-news-app) and run the same command, still got the same error.
2. Search for any issue and solution on Github, but no luck.

How could I resolve this issue? Or I missed anything? Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar issue with my Vite project. Did you manage to resolve the issue? Figure out what the cause is?

Comment: @GuyPassy, sorry, it's been a while. The answer didn't resolve my issue as well.

Comment: Hi I am experiencing the same error.. Did you solve this issue by any chance?

Comment: Same issue but only in Chrome (after it's update). The `/@vite/client/` url just doesn't load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have for sure an issue with your Node environment setup as **the project build and run successfully**.

Tested on `Node v14.17.5` with `npm v6.14.14` or `yarn v1.22.5`

For troubleshooting :

- https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm
- [How to Reinstall Broken npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748307/how-to-reinstall-broken-npm)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue but only in Chrome. The `/@vite/client/` url wasn't loading.

My issue was that Chrome has cached the url with the `/` in the end however it shouldn't be there. The only way to fix it was to open the Network tab in the dev tools, set a checkmark for "Disable cache", reload the page.