# npx create-react-app <app name> doing nothing no error no installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

When I try to create a react application using `npx create-react-app blog` it seems like nothing happened as you can see in this image

[image]

I have also tried to reinstall node js but it could not help me at all.

**Note: I have tried after removing the spaces between the folder name**

If I try to uninstall the globally installed react app the same issue, doesn't affect anything:

[image]

**Note:** `I don't have much knowledge but i messed up with proxy last time before this issue.`

Comment: can you check if your "blog" folder is not having an **only-read** permission ? it happened to me in the past but i'm not sure if it's the case for yourse

Comment: Could be an issue with spaces in directory name `mern stack projects`

Comment: I have checked both the solutions but still not working for me.

Comment: `npm -v` not displaying version, try reinstalling - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748307/how-to-reinstall-broken-npm

Answer (score 0):

Try installing npm first:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Then install the `create-react-app` package.

```
npm install create-react-app
```

Thanks.

Comment: If it doesn't work. Tag Me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still does not work on my end. Every command responds empty space, nothing else happening.