# Angular autosave does not work after some time

Tags: angular

I am writing my application in Angular. And in the beginning, it worked fine and reloaded the page when I saved changes to any file. But now it does not save changes in only one file. When I press Ctrl-S, the file is saved, but the page does not reload, and I have to restart the server.

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.app.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": false }
}
```

I use Windows 10. Any solution for this?

Comment: Just a step in the right direction - I think you mean hot reload/restart, and not autosave. :) Also, I have a similar issue on Ubuntu sometimes. Running ng serve with sudo seems to fix my issue.

Comment: So, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335456/angular-cli-auto-reload-doesnt-happen

Comment: I work on Wondows 10 :)

Comment: You can try other answers which were mentioned in url posted by @saglamcem

Comment: @programmer  can you share stackblitz url of your page