# How can i make my server detect modification in angular, if i use a lib with ng build

Tags: angular

I need your help,

My question is in our project angular, we use in script :
run build my-project && npm install ./dist/my-project
and then ng serve.

All is ok, the server start,

But when i modify something, the server does not restart automatically. When i asked my friend in the team, he says it normal that the server does not restart and does not detect modification because we use "ng build" we have a lib, and we should modify this..

You have an idea ? what i can do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ng build` solely builds files and places them in the output folder. It does not serve them or communicate with a web browser in any way. This is the function of `ng serve` which is designed specifically to provide the functionality required.

Also check this stackoverflow similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335456/angular-cli-auto-reload-doesnt-happen) maybe this might help you somehow. But its ng serve that hot reloads or detect changes etc

Comment: Thanks @wahab i will check the post to see if i find something.

Comment: i use this : rm -rf nodes_modules et i use npm install  and ng serve --> but i have the same error my server not detect changes !!

Comment: are you using linux, if so, try ng serve with sudo?

Comment: i use windows 10